# Principal stresses in state of pure shear

Tags: linear-algebra, classical-mechanics

Consider the stress tensor

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \tau & \tau \\
\tau & 0 & \tau\\
\tau & \tau & 0 
\end{bmatrix}

To find the principal stresses with the characteristic equation we get

$ \sigma^3 - 3 \tau^2 \sigma  - 2\tau^3 = 0$

and the Mohr's circle reduces to a point.

How to find the principal stresses and directions.

Comment: Also there is a mistake in the characteristic equation, it should be $-2\tau^3$

Comment: The determinant is $2\tau^3$.

Comment: Yes it is, but you started by $\sigma^3$ and not $-\sigma^3$, which means you are writing down $\det(\sigma \text{Id}_3-M)$, whose value at $\sigma=0$ is $-\det M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

You have an obvious direction $(1,1,1)$ associated with the principal stress $2\tau$. This tells you that the characteristic polynomial has $(\sigma-2\tau)$ as a factor. Can you then find the other factor?
$$ \sigma^3 - 3 \tau^2 \sigma - 2\tau^3 = (\sigma-2\tau)(a\sigma^2+b\sigma+c)\Longrightarrow a=1, c=\tau^2,\ldots$$

It will be a quadratic expression, so finding the other two roots should not be a problem.

Then to find the other directions for the other two roots, this is two linear systems to solve:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \tau & \tau \\
\tau & 0 & \tau\\
\tau & \tau & 0 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2\\
v_3 
\end{bmatrix}=\sigma\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2\\
v_3 
\end{bmatrix}$$
replacing $\sigma$ by the roots that you have found.

Comment: Does $2\tau$ satisfy the characterstic equation? $\tau$ would satisfy the characterstic equation and would be a eigen value.

Comment: @Raptor It should definitely, since when you multiply $(1,1,1)$ by the matrix you get $2\tau$ times $(1,1,1)$. Right now it doesn't, and that's how you know there is a mistake in the equation (see comment).